# How do I add a post cost to the checkout page?

Tags: 6, ubercart

I want to add a fixed post cost to the checkout page in ubercart 2(drupal6). How do I add it?

Currently I have this.

```
Order total preview:
Subtotal:       1000
Order total:    1000
```

I want this.

```
Order total preview:
Subtotal:       1000
Post cost:       400
Order total:    1400
```

Comment: Can you be more specific. Im not sure i understand what you are trying to do. Have you tried this using the Rules module?

Comment: @ANDiTKO Please see the edited post.

Comment: What do you mean by "Post cost"? And when this line item will be added to the user's checkout?